# JQuery - Looping through table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to loop through each `tr` in my table and get the value of each td where `td` is a certain class.

I'm populating my table like this:

```
    var attr = "checked";

    $('#mytbody').prepend('<tr><td class="cb" value="' + attr + '"><input type="checkbox" ' + attr + ' disabled class="filterPaid" id="invPaid' + i + '" value="outstanding" name="filterTasks[]"></td>.......</tr>');
```

I'm trying to search like this:

```
$("#paidFilter").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $('#mytbody  > tr > td.cb').each(function(){
            console.log($(this).val());
        });   
    }
});
```

However this doesn't return any values for the `td` of class = 'cb'.

How could these values be retrieved?

Comment: just for clarification purposes, are you trying to find that value of the td or the input thats inside the td?

Comment: Did you check if `this.checked` is true?

Comment: a `td` has no `value`, use a `data-` attribute. `val()` only works on form elements

Comment: @indubitablee, it will be the value of the `td`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/129/

`.val()` of a td element doesnt exist like it does for an input.  for the td, value is an attribute, so you access it by `.attr('value')`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mytbody  > tr > td.cb').each(function(){
        console.log($(this).attr('value'));
        $(this).append($(this).attr('value'));
    });   
});

<table>
    <tbody id="mytbody">
        <tr>
            <td class="cb" value="checked">CB should append value here:</td>
            <td class="cb" value="checked">CB should append value here:</td>
            <td class="" value="checked">NOT CB</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="cb" value="checked">CB should append value here:</td>
            <td class="" value="checked">NOT CB</td>
            <td class="cb" value="checked">CB should append value here:</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

you were close :]  hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

`$().val()` is strictly intended to get `value=""` attributes from form inputs, such as `<input>` or `<textarea>`.

If you still wish to assign a `value=""` attribute to the `<td>` element (not recommended), you can retrieve it using `$('#mytbody').attr('value')`. The same can also be used to retrieve the value of any other attribute.